# Extensions of degree $1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

My doubt is very simple:

Let $F|K$ be a field extension, if $[F:K]=1$, what can we say about $F$ and $K$? can I say $F=K$?

I'm trying to prove the equality without success.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if $[K:F]=1$ than there is a basis $\mathcal{B}$ with $\text{span}(\mathcal{B}) = F$ 
This basis has just one element wich is $1$

Comment: @drhab I meant $K\subset F$

Comment: The degree $[F:K]$ is just the dimension of $F$ viewed as a $K$-vector space. But $K$ is a $1$ dimensional $K$-vector space over itself, so if $[F:K]=1$, then $F$ has a subspace $K$ of equal dimension over $K$, but from linear algebra that means $K=F$.

Answer (score 4):

$F$ is a $K$-vector space and $\{1\} \subseteq F$ is linearly independent. Hence, if $F$ is $1$-dimensional over $K$, $\{1\}$ is a basis and then $F = K \cdot 1 = K$.

Comment: More generally, if $R \subseteq S$ is a ring extension which is a free $R$-module of rank $1$, then $S=R$. In fact, if $\{e\}$ is a basis, then $e$ is a unit (since $1$ is an $R$-multiple of $e$) and $ee=re$ for some $r \in R$, so that $e=r \in R$ and then $S=R e = R$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\exists a \in K \setminus F$. Then $1, a$ are $F$-linearly independent. Proof: If $f_1, f_2 \in F$ such that $f_1 1 + f_2 a = 0$, it follows that $f_2 a = -f_1$. If $f_2 \neq 0$, then $a = - \frac{f_1}{f_2} \in F$, a contradiction. Otherwise, we have $f_1 = 0$ as well, i.e. the only solution is $f_1 = f_2 = 0$. Thus $1, a$ are $F$-linearly independent.

Of course, there cannot exist two $F$-linearly independent elements in $K$ if $[K:F]=1$.

**Edit:** Sorry for the change in notation, I assumed $F \subset K$.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that $[F:K] = 1$ means that as a $K$-vector space, $F$ has a basis of cardinality $1$. Let us suppose this basis is $B = \{k_0\}$.

Since a basis is a spanning set, this means that for ANY $\alpha \in F$, we have: $\alpha = c\cdot k_0$ for some $c \in K$. But the $K$-action (scalar multiplication) of $F$ as an extension field of $K$ is just the $F$-multiplication.

So $\alpha = ck_0$. Now as a subring of $F$, $K$ is closed under multiplication, so we conclude $F \subseteq K$.

Since $F$ is an extension of $K$, we have *a priori*, $K \subseteq F$, thus the two are equal.

Comment: This argument is not complete since you use $k_0 \in K$.